# Is it possible to keep track of how many times a Python Script has been ran without writing to a file?

Tags: python, operating-system, execution, counting, atexit

I am curious whether it is possible to keep track of the number of times a specific .py file is ran without ever reading and writing to/from a file.

This thread: [how can i count how many time program has been executed in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30961310/how-can-i-count-how-many-time-program-has-been-executed-in-python)

uses atexit module to update a json file and log the number of times the script has ran in its lifetime. I guess this type of data must be logged in a file?

Comment: To my knowledge there is no way to accomplish this without some sort of logging/writing to file.  I'm just curious as to why you'd want this with such a limitation?

Comment: you could have it communicate with some other process, like a server, and have it keep track. However, if the server went down you would lose your info. It would be much easier to use a file.

Comment: It doesn't have to be written specifically to a file, but the information has to be stored _somewhere_.  Could be memory, file, database, etc.

Comment: @n1c9 I am writing some Selenium scripts. I just wanted to see if a short and sweet script can exist to keep track of this. I guess data has to be stored somewhere. Might as well write to a file I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using one example how to set environment variables from [Why can't environmental variables set in python persist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716011/why-cant-environmental-variables-set-in-python-persist):

You can have script, which sets environment variable in parent shell:

```
import pipes
import os
value = int(os.environ['MY_COUNTER']) + 1 if 'MY_COUNTER' in os.environ else 1
print("export MY_COUNTER=%s" % (pipes.quote(str(value))))
```

and run this script with command:

```
eval $(python example.py)
```

Then each run will increment `MY_COUNTER` by 1.

Of course, this environment variable will not persists, it's only in memory.

Comment: This would only work if the script didn't produce any other output. It also assumes that the script will always be run from a POSIX-compliant shell.

Comment: @chepner It's just an example, one can always redirecting output `eval $(python example.py 2>&1 >/dev/null)` and print the `MY_COUNTER` to stderr (or to some other file descriptor)

Comment: @AndrejKesely Cool answer, thanks! I think for my Selenium scripting purpose, this will do. I just want to run a script, come back 20 minutes later and see how many times it ran. I don't need to save it.

Comment: Pretty clever to use env variables for this!